# How to access data after redirect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Again there are multiple articles which says how to access data after redirect. but doesn't serves my purpose.

I am having errorcontroller which is having index action method and error index view.

If there is any error in the application it will caught in Application_Error event.

inside Application_Error event I had logged the error and redirected to Error Index page like this -

```
protected new void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Exception error = Server.GetLastError();
     log.error(error.Message);
     HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/Error/Index");
}
```

Now in the error index view, I would like to display the error message. What should I do in Application_Error event which can be access by Error Index view?

Updated : I don't want to use Session as session object may not be available in Application_Error event. this is dependent on when the error occurred.

Comment: @PKKG, yep as of now using TempData....accepted your answer as  it contains more details. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Approach - 1**

*As per my knowledge you can use TempData to store the posted data. It is like a DataReader Class, once read, Data will be lost. So that stored data in TempData will become null.*

```
var Value = TempData["keyName"] //Once read, data will be lost
```

*So to persist the data even after the data is read you can Alive it like below*

```
var Value = TempData["keyName"];
TempData.Keep();                   //Data will not be lost for all Keys
TempData.Keep("keyName");          //Data will not be lost for this Key
```

*TempData works in new Tabs/Windows also, like Session variable does.*

*You could use Session Variable also, Only major problem is that Session Variable are very heavy comparing with TempData. Finally you are able to keep the data across Controllers/Area also.*

**Approach - 2**

*This works for me. This is very easy and no need to consider any change in Web.Config or Register the Action Filter in Global.asax file.*

ok. So, First I am creating a simple *Action Filter*. This will handle Ajax and Non Ajax requests.

```
public class MyCustomErrorAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        var debugModeMsg = filterContext.HttpContext.IsDebuggingEnabled
                               ? filterContext.Exception.Message +
                                 "\n" +
                                 filterContext.Exception.StackTrace
                               : "Your error message";
```

//*This is the case when you need to handle Ajax requests*

```
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
            {
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
                Data = new
                {
                    error = true,
                    message = debugModeMsg
                }
            };
        }
```

//*This is the case when you handle Non Ajax request*

```
        else
        {
            var routeData = new RouteData();
            routeData.Values["controller"] = "Error";
            routeData.Values["action"] = "Error";
            routeData.DataTokens["area"] = "app";
            routeData.Values["exception"] = debugModeMsg;
            IController errorsController = new ErrorController();
            var exception = HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError();
            var httpException = exception as HttpException;
            if (httpException != null)
            {
                Response.StatusCode = httpException.GetHttpCode();
                switch (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode)
                {
                    case 504:
                        routeData.Values["action"] = "Http404";
                        break;
                }
            }

            var rc = new RequestContext
                         (
                             new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current),
                             routeData
                         );
            errorsController.Execute(rc);
        }
        base.OnException(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Now you can implement this Action Filter on Controller as well as on the Action only.Example:

[image]

I am going little off topic. I thought this is bit important to explain.

If you pay attention to the above highlighted part. I have specified the order of the Action Filter. This basically describes the order of execution of Action Filter. This is a situation when you have multiple Action Filters implemented over Controller/Action Method

[image]

*This picture just indicates that let's say you have two Action Filters. `OnActionExecution` will start to execute on Priority and `OnActionExecuted` will start from bottom to Top. That means in case of `OnActionExecuted` Action Filter having highest order will execute first and in case of `OnActionExecuting` Action Filter having lowest order will execute first. Example below.*

```
public class Filter1 : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
```

//Execution will start here - 1

```
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
```

//Execution will move here - 5

```
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}

public class Filter2 : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
```

//Execution will move here - 2

```
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
```

//Execution will move here - 4

```
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}

[HandleError]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Filter1(Order = 1)]
    [Filter2(Order = 2)]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
```

//Execution will move here - 3

```
        ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

        return View();
    }
}
```

You may already aware that there are different types of filters within MVC framework. They are listed below.

1. Authorization filters
2. Action filters
3. Response/Result filters
4. Exception filters

Within each filter, you can specify the Order property. This basically describes the order of execution of the Action Filters.

Answer (score 1):

Use `TempData` for getting value.

Some feature about `TempData`

- **TempData** is a dictionary object that is derived from TempDataDictionary class and stored in short lives session.
- **TempData** is used to pass data from current request to subsequent request means incase of redirection.
- It’s life is very short and lies only till the target view is fully loaded.
- It’s required typecasting for complex data type and check for null values to avoid error.
- It is used to store only one time messages like error messages, validation messages.